# Setting a default value on form start for DomainUpDown Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have some `DomainUpDown` controls in my winforms application. I cant find an option to set the default value for them on start up. Is there a way to do this?

At the moment, I have an enum type like this:

```
public enum ComparisonMode {Settings, Readings};
```

And I have set the `SelectedItemChanged` event of each DomainUpDown control to something like this:

```
private ComparisonMode ComparisonA; //enum to hold state of upDownA

private void upDownA_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (upDownA.Text)
    {
        case "Settings":
            ComparisonA = ComparisonMode.Settings;
            break;

        case "Readings":
           ComparisonA = ComparisonMode.Readings;
            break;
    }
}
```

When I start the application, all the domainupdown controls have nothing selected, so user must set each of them to either Settings or Readings befor starting to work with the application.

How can I set for all of them a default value of for example (Readings)? I am thinking of looping over the controls (As they are inside a `TableLayoutPanel`).

I came up with this idea so far, It seems to work:

```
    foreach (TableLayoutPanel tlp in tableCriterias.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in tlp.Controls)
        {
            var dud = ctrl as DomainUpDown;                

            if (dud != null)
            {
                dud.DownButton(); dud.DownButton();
                //Going down 2 times to select default value
            }
        }
    }
```

I do the above loop in the `Load` event of my form, but it makes everything very slow in the beggining since I have like 100 of these UpDown Controls.

Comment: Why don't set the default value in winforms dialogs when the controls are created?

Comment: I didn't see that or I forgot. Now I can't see any option to set default value for them. Also if theire value is changed another variable which is an enum, should be changed. So just showing the text in them is not enough and they should have effect on another variable of type Enum that I wrote up there.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. what is ComparasisonA in the code you should above? can't you do the same thing, except in your initialization code?

Comment: Ok please see the updated question. `ComparisonA` is a variable of enum `ComparisonMode`.

Comment: See my answer, you don't need to do this, just set it when you initialize your form

Comment: Just derive your own class from DomainUpDown to give it specialized behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do this, you can set the SelectedIndex like this :

```
    DomainUpDown dd = new DomainUpDown();
    dd.Items.Add("settings");
    dd.Items.Add("Reading");
    dd.SelectedIndex = 0; // this will make sure you get the first item selected
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this mean I have to go and set this for each of about 100 UpDown controls in the form.designer.cs file?! damn I am lazy :D

Comment: lo,, btw even in your automatic loop you can do dud.SelectedIndex = 0 instead of DownButton() twice.